# Spectrum of complete bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I've been tasked with the following:

- Prove that a complete bipartite graph with n + m nodes has a spectrum $(\sqrt{mn} ,0,..,0,-\sqrt{mn})$
- Prove that a complete graph with n nodes has a spectrum $(n-1,-1,..,-1)$

I completely understand what those graphs are, but I didn't know where I should start. I would be glad for any help.

Comment: Start by writing down their adjacency matrices and looking at those to figure out what you can say about their eigenvalues. Some of these eigenvalues are clear from looking at $A - \lambda I$, and for some you'll need to guess an eigenvector.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I don't know where to start". The standard place to start is to look at your notes or book to see if there are related questions with worked solutions. Did you do this? (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for the Hint

Comment: @user1729  You are right, but the thing is i am not a math student, i am a mechanical engineer Student and for this semester i choose a course for advanced Mathematic, so it is my first time working with Prooving things and math assignements. I just want to learn for such problems how i should start.  But thank you for the advice

Comment: @BahrouniAhmedDhia Thanks for your reply. You should say this in your question, as it is context. It would also help if you told us about any similar exercises in your notes about spectrum (so for example someone might say that it follows from *this* proof in your notes, you just need to alter *that* bit, or something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph. Notice $A^2$ is a block diagonal matrix, in which there is a block of $m$'s of size $n$ and a block of $n$'s of size $m$. it follows the spectrum of $A^2$ is $\{[nm]^2,[0]^{n+m-2}\}$.

Therefore the spectrum of $A$ is as desired (since the trace is $0$).

For the second problem let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph. Notice $A+I$ is the constant $1$ matrix, which has spectrum $\{[n]^1,[0]^{n-1}\}$, it follows $A$ has spectrum $\{[n-1],[-1]^{n-1}\}$

Comment: Please read the new update decision from the moderator team, in meta.math: [Enforcement of Quality Standards (and how they relate to answering poor quality questions)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was really helpfull :D

Comment: Glad to have been able to help !